# jtable child table not POSTing key value

Tags: jquery-jtable

I have a Jquery jtable that has a child table.  As far as I can see it is set up as per the example in the jtable demos.  The main tables= (contacts) and the child tables (categories) display without any problem.  My problem is that the delete action on the **category** child table is not posting the row key value (categoryID) as I would expect it to and I cannot see why not. The similar action on the main table posts its just fine. Note the two console.log lines in the code below that output the postData variable, the first one reports the ID of the contact table line (ID), but the second one prints an empty array instead of the CategoryID.  Any help appreciated.

Thanks

```
function ReturnAjax(theurl, postdata, errorfn) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: theurl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: postdata,
        cache: false,
        error: errorfn
    });             
}

    $('#ContactsTableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'Contacts',
    paging: true,
    pageSize: 30,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'LastName ASC',
    selecting: true,
    selectOnRowClick: true,
    openChildAsAccordion: true,
    deleteConfirmation: false,
    actions: {
        listAction: function(postData, jtParams) {
            console.log("ContactsTableContainer - Loading list from custom function...");
            return $.Deferred(function($dfd) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ContactsData.php?action=list&jtStartIndex=' + jtParams.jtStartIndex + '&jtPageSize=' + jtParams.jtPageSize + '&jtSorting=' + jtParams.jtSorting,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: postData,
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data['RowIDs']) { RowIDs = data['RowIDs'].toString().split(','); }
                        $dfd.resolve(data);
                    },
                    error: MyError
                });
            });
        },
        deleteAction: function(postData) {
            console.log('deleting from contacts - custom function..., '+JSON.stringify(postData));
            $.when(
                ReturnAjax(
                    'ContactsData.php?action=list&ContactID='+postData['ID'],
                    postData,
                    MyError
                )
            ).then(
                function(data) {
                    if (data.Result != 'OK') { alert(data.Message); }
                    var msg = '';
                    var len = data.Records.length;
                    if(len>0) {
                        msg = '\t'+data.Records[0].Category;
                        for(var i=1 ; i<len ; i++) { msg += '\n\t'+data.Records[i].Category; }
                        msg = 'Contact is in the following categories\n'+msg;
                    }
                    msg += '\n\nConfirm deletion of this contact';
                    if(confirm(msg)) {
                        $.when(
                            ReturnAjax(
                                'ContactsData.php?action=delete',
                                postData,
                                MyError
                            )
                        ).done(
                            $('#ContactsTableContainer').jtable('reload')
                        );
                    } else {
                        $('#ContactsTableContainer').jtable('reload'); // Had to put this here to ensure that same delete button could be used again
                    }       
                }
            ).fail( function() { console.log('ajax call went wrong'); } );
        }, // end of delete action
    }, // end of actions
    fields: {
        ID: {
            key: true,
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: false,
            visibility: 'hidden'
        },
        Categories: {
            title: '',
            width: '5%',
            sorting: false,
            create: false,
            display: function(contact) {
                var $img = $('<img src="Images/layers.png" title="Show contact\'s categories" />');
                //Open child table when user clicks the image
                $img.click(function() {
                    console.log('display function (contact)..., '+JSON.stringify(contact));
                    $('#ContactsTableContainer').jtable(
                        'openChildTable',
                        $img.closest('tr'), //Parent row
                        {
                            title: contact.record.Name + ' - Categories',
                            selecting: true,
                            selectOnRowClick: true,
                            actions: {
                                listAction: 'ContactsData.php?action=list&ContactID=' + contact.record.ID,
                                deleteAction: function(postData) {
                                    console.log('deleting from custom category function..., '+JSON.stringify(postData));
                                    $.when(
                                        ReturnAjax(
                                            'ContactsData.php?action=deleteAssignment&ContactID=' + contact.record.ID,
                                            postData,
                                            MyError
                                        )
                                    ).done(
                                        $('#ContactsTableContainer').jtable('reload')
                                    );
                                }
                            },
                            fields: {
                                CategoryID: { key: true, create: false, edit: false, list: false, visibility: 'hidden' },
                                ContactID: { type: 'hidden', defaultValue: contact.record.ID },
                                Category: { title: 'Category' }
                            }
                        },
                        function(data) { data.childTable.jtable('load'); }
                    );
                });
                //Return image to show on the person row
                return $img;
            }
        },
        FirstName: {
            title: 'Forename',
            width: '25%',
        },
        LastName: {
            title: 'Surname',
            width: '25%',
        },
        HomePhone: {
            title: 'Phone',
            width: '15%',
            sorting: false,
        },
        Mobile: {
            title: 'Mobile',
            width: '15%',
            sorting: false,
        },
        Email: {
            title: 'Email',
            width: '20%',
            sorting: false,
        },
        Name: {
            type: 'hidden'
        },
    }
});

//Load list from server
$('#ContactsTableContainer').jtable('load');
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it, sorry to bother anyone who may have spent time looking at this.  The problem was that my child table variable names were wrong they should have been category_ID and Contact_ID